# Convert Julian/Ordinal date to date in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I need to convert this string `2020121` as `2020-04-30` in SQL Server?

How do I do that?

Comment: Why store strings instead of dates *at all* ?

Comment: This is not a Julian day, it's just the year concatted with an ordinal using the start of the year as the epoch, an Ordinal date, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date

Comment: @AndrewMorton unlike what that paragraph says, using `Julian Day` this way is definitely not common in computer programming. It may be common for programmers in the food industry, but definitely not for programming in general

Comment: It's not common either way, but it *does* tell us what the industry is. In your link the "reference" is a scanned table from an unspecified 1963 USDA document. In that particular sector a bad named remained and became "standard". I've actually encountered a similar situation with airline systems, where `¥` is used called `Cross-of-Lorraine` (☨) probably because that's what their terminals showed 40 years ago. Even in web service calls

Answer (score 1):

I think that your use of Julian date is the number of days (minus 1) since the start of the year.  If so, you can use:

```
select dateadd(day,
               convert(int, right(string, 3)) - 1,
               datefromparts(convert(int, left(string, 4)), 1, 1)
              )
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b65dce9dffec3bf3a3cb7a8ab66df7e8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Would `substring(string, 5, 3)` be better in case the day-of-year number is less than 100?

Comment: @AndrewMorton . . . That is a good point.